# How do they shoot the shotgun scene?

Tags: production, mindhunter-2017

In the first episode of Mindhunter, the hostage negotiation unceremoniously ends when the hostage taker shoots himself in the face with a shotgun.
[image: A second after he pulls the trigger]
This is a pretty realistic looking visual effect and there was almost no pause between when the actor pointed the gun at his face and when he pulled the trigger. What trick is used in production to achieve this effect?